# U.2 hotswapping in linux?

Tags: linux, ssd

I have a Debian 11 and a U.2 SSD which is supposed to be hot-swappable; this is my kernel:

```
root@eris:~# uname -a
Linux eris 5.18.0-0.bpo.1-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 5.18.2-1~bpo11+1 (2022-06-14) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The drive is mounted in a 'ICY DOCK U.2 NVMe SSD Mobile Rack' and is detected fine at boot, I can format and mount it; however, when I pull it out of the rack, the kernel doesn't detect the change (nothing in `dmesg`), and when I put it back in, `mount` and other commands can't find it either.

I found this article [about the same in AIX](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/power9/9009-22A?topic=rrnud-preparing-system), and perhaps there are some steps I ought to perform before just pulling the drive out - in AIX you would first tell the system to 'unconfigure' the drive, for example.

So, am I doing something wrong, and if so, what do I need to do to fix this issue?

Comment: IMHO you use different hardware from the article of IBM. So you can't make reasonable speculations.

Comment: Yes, different HW and OS, but this is only meant as an example of how it might work in Linux. I have worked enough with all the UNIXes (>15 years) to know that they are similar enough that you can make reasonable assumptions. U.2 and PCIe are supposed to support hot-swapping, so I think it is mostly a question of figuring out how to get the Linux kernal to support it.

Comment: A U.2 NVMe device is effectively a PCIe device with a differently-shaped connector. So the question becomes, does your system hardware/firmware support PCIe hotplugging or not? Hotplugging is part of the PCIe standard, but if the motherboard is not designed with hotplugging in mind (e.g. with the capability to switch power off individual PCIe slots or U.2 connectors), then the ACPI firmware is not likely to implement the hotplug features either.

Comment: @telcoM That makes a lot of sense - is there a a way to query the ACPI firmware?

Comment: That's a good question. I don't know. But if your hardware supports PCIe hotplugging, its documentation should say so. Server-grade systems would be likely to include hotplugging features; motherboards for home desktops, less so. So it's time to Read the Fine Manual of your (unspecified) hardware.

Comment: @telcoM Heh, my HW manual tells me a lot about how to connect LEDs so I can impress my gamer friends. The motherboard is a ROG STRIX X570 GAMING, not that we play games, officially, but it seems gaming PCs are relatively cheap and the good people that came before me that they are useful for numerical processing in combination with a GPU the size of a loaf of bread. Unfortunately I haven't found information about PCI hotplugging for this one.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to do what I need, namely 'unconfigure' and 'configure' the drive as part of hotplugging it. This is what I've done, so far, and it is actually relatively simple:

These are my block devices:

```
root@eris:~# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1     259:0    0  3.6T  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0  476M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 38.1G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0  3.6T  0 part /data
nvme1n1     259:4    0  3.5T  0 disk /test
```

The one I want to unconfigure - ie remove from the list of block devices - is `nvme1n1`. You now need to find the right device address on the PCI bus, which is mapped as a directory tree under `/sys/bus/pci` - the easiest way is like this:

```
root@eris:~# for i in /sys/block/nvme*
> do
>   echo "$i is $(cat $i/device/address)"
> done
/sys/block/nvme0n1 is 0000:01:00.0
/sys/block/nvme1n1 is 0000:04:00.0
```

This shows that `nvme1n1` corresponds to `/sys/bus/pci/drivers/nvme/0000:04:00.0`:

```
root@eris:~# ll /sys/bus/pci/drivers/nvme/0000:04:00.0/
total 0
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Jul  7 09:24 aer_dev_correctable
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Jul  7 09:24 aer_dev_fatal
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Jul  7 09:24 aer_dev_nonfatal
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Jul  7 09:24 ari_enabled
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Jul  7 09:24 broken_parity_status
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Jul  7 08:04 class
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Jul  7 09:24 config
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Jul  7 09:24 consistent_dma_mask_bits
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Jul  7 09:24 current_link_speed
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Jul  7 09:24 current_link_width
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Jul  7 09:24 d3cold_allowed
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Jul  7 08:04 device
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Jul  7 09:24 dma_mask_bits
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     0 Jul  7 08:04 driver -> ../../../../../../bus/pci/drivers/nvme
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Jul  7 09:24 driver_override
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Jul  7 09:24 enable
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     0 Jul  7 09:24 firmware_node -> ../../../../../LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:3b/device:3c/device:41/device:42
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     0 Jul  7 09:24 iommu -> ../../../../0000:00:00.2/iommu/ivhd0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     0 Jul  7 09:24 iommu_group -> ../../../../../../kernel/iommu_groups/21
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Jul  7 09:24 irq
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     0 Jul  7 09:24 link/
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Jul  7 09:24 local_cpulist
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Jul  7 09:24 local_cpus
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Jul  7 09:24 max_link_speed
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Jul  7 09:24 max_link_width
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Jul  7 09:24 modalias
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Jul  7 09:24 msi_bus
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     0 Jul  7 09:24 msi_irqs/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Jul  7 09:24 numa_node
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     0 Jul  7 08:04 nvme/
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Jul  7 09:24 pools
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     0 Jul  7 09:24 power/
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Jul  7 09:24 power_state
--w--w---- 1 root root  4096 Jul  7 09:24 remove
--w------- 1 root root  4096 Jul  7 09:24 rescan
--w------- 1 root root  4096 Jul  7 09:24 reset
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Jul  7 09:24 reset_method
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Jul  7 09:24 resource
-rw------- 1 root root 16384 Jul  7 09:24 resource0
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Jul  7 08:04 revision
-rw------- 1 root root 65536 Jul  7 09:24 rom
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     0 Jul  7 08:10 subsystem -> ../../../../../../bus/pci
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Jul  7 08:04 subsystem_device
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Jul  7 08:04 subsystem_vendor
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Jul  7 09:24 uevent
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Jul  7 08:04 vendor
```

The one I need here is `remove`, a write-only file. To take the SSD device out of the list of block devices:

```
root@eris:~# echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/nvme/0000:04:00.0/remove
root@eris:~# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1     259:0    0  3.6T  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0  476M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 38.1G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0  3.6T  0 part /data
```

It takes several seconds, so don't panic! To get it back:

```
root@eris:~# echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan
root@eris:~# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1     259:0    0  3.6T  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0  476M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 38.1G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0  3.6T  0 part /data
nvme1n2     259:5    0  3.5T  0 disk
```

Note, however, that `nvme1n1` has become `nvme1n2` - that is something I still have to figure out, but I can now hotplug my U.2 drive.

Comment: [This question at Electronics.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/208767/does-pcie-hotplug-actually-work-in-practice) describes what kind of things are needed at the hardware side for hotplugging, and I also found [this product](https://quarch.com/products/gen4-pcie-u2-module/) (technically test equipment) that might allow you to add the necessary power control features to a system that doesn't have them, if you want to do it Absolutely Right. But if your solution works, good for you.